# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, git-bash

I've created a database laravel from phpmyadmin. Now Im using console but it's showing this error 1044 - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database laravel. I have written mysql laravel. trying to navigate to database. 
I tried to grant all privileges with the following:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';`
In my laravel folder my env file is:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=xWbA7b570ft2AYdc10dCX56CwwvaZlQs

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Also in my environment path in system settings I've set path to mysql and commands could be run, but it's showing this error for no access.
But it's still showing this error.
Would you help me with that?

Comment: The `root` userid has access to everything in MYSQL by default, it is the `SuperUser`. You do not need to grant any other acess to that Userid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the `mysql` command line processor like this

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

The `-u` is the Userid that you are login on to MySQL with, note there is no space between the parameter `-u` and the userid.  The `-p`, without entering the password will cause the `mysql` command line processor to challenge you for the password. If you have not set a password just hit enter and it will proceed.

Once the processor start you then need to tell MYSQL which database you want to use for the commands you are then going to issue. So do :-

```
mysql> use database_name;
```

In your case I assume it would be

```
mysql> use laravel;
```

And then for example :-

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
```

Comment: Yes, I did it, but after that I enter `mysql laravel` and nothing happens.

Comment: See additional instructions

Comment: Thanks, now it's fine :) How about should I see table `users` for example?